# netezza connection refused in r studio

Tags: r, jdbc, rstudio, dbi, netezza

I'm having difficulty connecting to the database.

```
library(RJDBC)
library(DBI)

driver <- JDBC(driverClass = "org.netezza.Driver", classPath = "C:\\nzjdbc.jar", "'")

conn <- dbConnect(driver, "URL", "ID", "Password")
```

The following error appears when I ran the code.

> Error in .jcall(drv@jdrv, "Ljava/sql/Connection;", "connect", as.character(url)[1],  : 
>     org.netezza.error.NzSQLException: netezza.con.refused

The first time I tried to connect to the database before using the dbSendquery function, the connection was not refused. But, when I tried this time, I got the error. Is this just a problem with Netezza?

Comment: Can you currently connect directly to Netezza using the same credentials?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I keep getting refused

Comment: Then the problem is on the database, probably not in the R code (given that the code was working previously).  So at least now you know where to start looking for a solution.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thats's exactly what I figured. But then why does the Netezza connection get refused??? I also tried this in Knime and it shows practically the same error.

Comment: Are you literally passing `"URL"` as the connection URL? If not, what value are you passing?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, no I am not using URL as the connection URL. The URL that I used was in this format: jdbc:netezza:// But it turns out that Netezza doesn't automatically connect. So I was able to connect a few hours later, so again this is purely a problem with Netezza, not with R.